# hibernate.cache.region.factory_class Required in hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: hibernate, memcached

I am working on using memcache as second level cache for Hibernate. I am using hibernate-memcached-1.2.4, spymemcached 2.8.0 and hibernate 4.1.4.

But when i try to use it , it gives me error saying

```
    Initial sessionfactory creation failedorg.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given, please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory class name to property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class (and make sure the second level cache provider, hibernate-infinispan, for example, is available in the classpath).
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at Util.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:16)
        at hibba.AccountDAOimpl.getAccount(AccountDAOimpl.java:23)
        at hibba.Connect.main(Connect.java:7)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given, please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory class name to property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class (and make sure the second level cache provider, hibernate-infinispan, for example, is available in the classpath).
        at org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildTimestampsRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache.(UpdateTimestampsCache.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:510)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1744)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1782)
        at Util.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:12)
        ... 2 more
```

The properties written in hibernate.cfg.xml is:

```
<pre>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">com.googlecode.hibernate.memcached.MemcachedCacheProvider </property>
        <property name="hibernate.memcached.memcacheClientFactory">com.googlecode.hibernate.memcached.dangamemcached.DangaMemcacheClientFactory</property>      
        <property name="hibernate.Memcached.servers"> localhost:11211 </property>
        <property name="hibernate.Memcached.cacheTimeSeconds">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.Memcached.connectionFactory">KetamaConnectionFactory</property> </pre>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882393/ehcache-hibernate-4/13882683#13882683

Answer (score 4):

The exception is quite self-explanatory. You have to set the *hibernate.cache.region.factory_class* property. For instance with ehcache would be adding the following line:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

Comment: -That is for ehcache... but i am using memcached and problem is hibernate-memcached does not provide region factory class. Kcarlson @github tried to do one but i m unable to find any jar for that...

Comment: @AnilKrShokeen Did you ever figure it out?  I'd love to know.  I'm currently stuck as well.

Comment: `net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory` is for Hibernate 3. For Hibernate 4, use 

`<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>`.

For details, see http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/integrations/hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue while using hibernate-memcached 1.3 and spymemcached 2.7 with hibernate 4.3. Had to switch to [hibernate4-memcached](https://github.com/kwon37xi/hibernate4-memcached) which provides a `RegionFactory`.