# ehcache hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

In my application I use the hibernate-core-4.1.8 jar and would like to take an ehCache as 2nd level cache. 
The jar I am currently using is ehcache-core-2.5.0. I placed it in my WebContetn/WEB-INF/lib folder and put it in the classpath too.

My hibernate.cfg.xml looks like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>   
    ....    
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

the ehcache.xml which is placed in the JavaResources/src folder:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
        monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    <defaultCache
                maxElementsInMemory="100000"
                eternal="false"
                timeToIdleSeconds="1000"
                timeToLiveSeconds="1000"
                overflowToDisk="false"
                />
</ehcache>
```

When running my application the class org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory is not found:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$1.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:99)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2283)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2279)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1748)
    at creator.controllers.MyFactory.<clinit>(MyFactory.java:18)
    at creator.controllers.SchoolDAO.getList(SchoolDAO.java:98)
    .....
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to include `hibernate-ehcache.jar` by [downloading it](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/4.0.0.CR6/hibernate-ehcache-4.0.0.CR6.jar) or is you're using maven put it in your dependencies like this

```
<dependency>
<artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<version>4.0.0.CR6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: works fine after adding your jar as well as the slf4-api-1.7.2 it seems to require (from http://www.slf4j.org/download.html) to the project :)
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your `hibernate version` and you have to use the same version of `hibernate-ehcache`