# Configure Query Cache in Hibernate4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching

I'm trying enable query cache in our application. As per the documentation I have given

`hibernate.cache.use_query_cache` as `true` and givent `setCacheable()` in my queries. But I'm getting below exception.

`org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given, please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory class name to property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class (and make sure the second level cache provider, hibernate-infinispan, for example, is available in the classpath).`

Should I specify cache region for query cache, I'm using Hibernate 4. Please help me in this regard

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303348/hibernate-nocacheregionfactoryavailableexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Following for hibernate 4.

I am using this with hibernate 4.3

```
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
```